# How do you control type defaulting in doctests

Tags: haskell, doctest, quickcheck

How does `doctest` decide what type defaulting rules to use?

I have written several doctests that I would like to default to `Double` (because of `RealFrac` or `Floating` contexts) that are instead failing because they are defaulting to `Integer` and the relevant instances are (for good reason) missing.

I tried adding `default (Integer, Double)` to my `$setup` named chunk, to no apparent effect.

I tried adding the `-XExtendedDefaultRules` option to my invocation of `doctest`, also to no apparent effect. I did this even though I don't think my particular example actually requires the extended default rules.

Comment: Just now I realized it might be -XNoMonomorphismRestriction because one of the tests involves a helper function defined in a `let` in `$setup`, which I thought was a really promising theory, but that didn't help either. Maybe I am putting the compiler options in the wrong place?